# copying a directory with a specific file

Tags: bash

I (very clearly) do not know Bash. If this is a redundant question, I will appreciate being pointed in the right direction -- apologies if I didn't find the appropriate thread. Thank you, as always.

I have a file structure as follows:

```
/quants
   sample1
      a bunch of extra stuff
      aux_info
         unmapped_names.txt
   sample2
      a bunch of extra stuff
      aux_info
         unmapped_names.txt
   sample3
      a bunch of extra stuff
      aux_info
         unmapped_names.txt
```

in each sample subdirectories, there are more directories and files than only aux_info and unmapped_names.txt, but these are the ones I'm interested in copying.

The method below creates a new directory, unmapped, inside /quants. The result is the following:

```
/quants
   sample1
      a bunch of extra stuff
      aux_info
         unmapped_names.txt
   sample2
      a bunch of extra stuff
      aux_info
         unmapped_names.txt
   sample3
      a bunch of extra stuff
      aux_info
         unmapped_names.txt
   unmapped
      sample1
         unmapped_names.txt
      sample2
         unmapped_names.txt
      sample3
         unmapped_names.txt
```

The code below works, but it is extremely slow. I'd appreciate suggestions on how to do this more efficiently.

```sh
getUnmapped(){
# =====================================================================
# description: create new dir called unmapped
# input: quant filepath (output from mapSalmon)
# output: 
# =====================================================================

# enable glob (for mac)
shopt -s extglob

# store original workingDir
local workingDir=$(pwd)
# store list of all directories (sample_rep names) in quant dir
local sample_dirs=$1/*

# cd to inputted quants dir
cd $1

# create directory in quants dir called unmappped
mkdir unmapped
cd unmapped

# create sample_rep directories in unmapped
for sample_rep in $sample_dirs;
  do
    if [ $(basename ${sample_rep%_quant}) != "unmapped" ]
      then
        local sample_file=$(basename ${sample_rep%_quant})
        mkdir $sample_file
        cp $sample_rep/aux_info/unmapped_names.txt ${1}/unmapped/${sample_file}
      fi
  done

cd $workingDir

} # end getUnmapped
```

Comment: What is it you want to do with this file structure?

Comment: I'll improve the description -- thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to do this in a programming language with perhaps parallelism built in. Otherwise you could use the command parallel perhaps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211976/how-to-run-x-instances-of-a-script-parallel

I'm not sure on the intricacies involved in parallel myself but it should at least start maximizing your utilization of resources. You can install parallel on Mac using Brew:
https://brew.sh/

Comment: Yeah -- this is probably the answer. I hoped that there might be a more efficient method in bash itself.

Answer (score 0):

How many files are you processing?

One thing you could do is precompute and store the expression:

$(basename ${sample_rep%_quant})

like this:

sample_file=$(basename ${sample_rep%_quant})

Then in your code replace the expression with $sample_file. This would save you from evaluating the expression twice. However I don't think that is why it's running slow since the performance is probably limited by your Mac's file system I/O.

With large 800MB files copying will be slow. In that case symlinking with 'ln -s ...' instead will be much faster.

Comment: Currently, only 6 sample files. However, other experiments will be larger, maybe in the ~18 - 30 range. Nothing enormous.

good point re: variable sample_file. cp is the slow part of this, it seems to me.

Comment: Why is copying 6 files slow? Are they big?

Comment: Great question. Each file is ~800 MB

Comment: I'm using macOS Mojave with a 3Ghz i5, 8GB. I'm not running anything else. Possibly the machine? it takes 2:30 minutes to complete.

Comment: Ah, it's slow because the files are large. You may want to consider moving the files with the 'mv' command, or symlinking with the 'ln -s' command. Both of these should be much faster, almost instant compared to copying all the data.

Comment: @Kevin sim link is obviously the answer -- that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you -- I knew there was something simple that I was overlooking.